# Which is a better option for making dosa batter. Indian mixie or US blender?

Tags: batter

Moving to US next week planning to avoid the Mixie as it weighs almost 3 kgs . Which is the best option in blenders for making soft batter and chutney? I have got few recommendations like Osterizer not sure if this can make soft batter

Answer (score 2):

You can buy Indian style
Mixie's in the USA. What I found was Preethi brand. They sell for what looks like between $150-$250USD. From the description of the appliance, they are spice grinders in addition to being mixers, so a blender may not be quite a proper substitute, however we do have a lot of blenders, food processors and standup mixers to choose from, so you may eventually have a full set of Kitchen appliances up to the task, but I think you will either want to bring your mixie or buy a new mixie when you get here if you want an appliance that does exactly what the mixie does.

I may even have to buy one now.

Comment: yep, MG 198 on the long term shopping list too :)

Answer (score 1):

Not much difference except the 'heavy dutyness' of the average mixie - a mixie *is* a blender. A good blender should be able to handle it though.

A wet grinder is superior to both - since its probably more powerful and dosen't heat up the batter. My mom's trick to perfect dosa in a blender or mixie was to blend an icecube or two with the batter so I'd look at models that can handle that, since something capable of crushing ice would likely do a good job on your dosa batter.